# Each cell wise operation based on condition in matlab

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, element, computation

I don't know whether this is possible without iterating the matrix, but here goes the question. For any given square matrix say 'M', and a particular value say 'key'.

I want to compute a new matrix (say 'NM') such that,

```
if M(i,j) < key; compute NM(i,j) using formula 1,
if M(i,j) = key; compute NM(i,j) using formula 2, and
if M(i,j) > key; compute NM(i,j) using formula 3
```

The output of the operation must be new square matrix of same dimension as that of M. Hope the problem is clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want this for a pure matrix solution, so I'll answer it that way. (You used the word [cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) in your title which has a specific meaning in Matlab)

First you need to define the matrix NM to be the same size as M, easy enough by just using one to define the other.  Then use logical indexing to only apply the values to the matrix elements you desire.

```
NM=M;
NM( M < key) = formula1( NM(M < key) );
NM( M == key) = formula2( NM(M == key) );
NM( M >= key) = formula3( NM(M > key) );
```

Here is an illustrative example that applies a single formula `NM=M+1` to the matrix elements which are less than 0.5.

```
>> M=rand(3)

M =

0.0623    0.7783    0.0097
0.7011    0.2843    0.7337
0.1984    0.2123    0.9778

>> NM=M;
>> NM(M<.5)=M(M<.5)+1

NM =

1.0623    0.7783    1.0097
0.7011    1.2843    0.7337
1.1984    1.2123    0.9778
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to do something like

```
NM(M < key) = formula1;
NM(M == key) = formula2;
NM(M > key) = formula3;
```

Depending on your formula, you may need to pass the values of M to the function, i.e.

```
NM(M < key) = formula1(M(M < key));
```